# Elasticsearch can't start on Windows Git Bash

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to start Elasticsearch using the command `bin/elasticsearch` but I'm getting an error that says `Could not find or load main class org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch` as shown below.

```
me@DESKTOP-T11JTA5 MINGW64 ~/elasticsearch-1.3.4
$ pwd
/c/Users/jacky/elasticsearch-1.3.4

me@DESKTOP-T11JTA5 MINGW64 ~/elasticsearch-1.3.4
$ ls
bin/  config/  lib/  LICENSE.txt  NOTICE.txt  README.textile

me@DESKTOP-T11JTA5 MINGW64 ~/elasticsearch-1.3.4
$ bin/elasticsearch
Error: Could not find or load main class org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
```

Comment: Did u find the solution for this? I too have an exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your `JAVA_HOME` is not pointing at your JRE 1.7 directory.

Try something like:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
```

Of course, changing the path to your real Java instalation path. If you don't, install [Oracle's Java 1.7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html)